# calling an instance variable obtained from an actionperformed in another JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have created a JFrame with cardLayout and the first visible JPanel has a Jbutton that I have added an action Listener to perform an action. The action creates a String variable 'hhhhh' that I want to use in another JPanel. This is what I have problem doing.

```
Class 1

    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class NHome extends JFrame{


    JPanel Bucket= new JPanel(), Start= new JPanel(), Cashier = new csView(), Manager = new JPanel();
    JButton stbtn= new JButton("Start"), mnbtn= new JButton("Manager"), csbtn= new JButton("Cashier");
    CardLayout cl= new CardLayout();
    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private JPasswordField passwordField;



    public NHome() {
    textField.setBounds(322, 141, 158, 31);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    Bucket.setLayout(cl);
    Bucket.add(Start, "1");
    Bucket.add(Cashier, "2");
    Bucket.add(Manager, "3");

    Start.setLayout(null);
    stbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    cl.show(Bucket, "2");

    /*
     * I want to use this value of this String in the another class (csView)
    */
    String hhhhh=new String("Peter");
    System.out.println(hhhhh);
        }
    });





    stbtn.setBounds(353, 245, 76, 23);
    Start.add(stbtn);

    Start.add(textField);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setBounds(322, 183, 158, 31);
    Start.add(passwordField);
    Cashier.setLayout(null);
    csbtn.setBounds(197, 139, 116, 23);

    Cashier.add(csbtn);
    Manager.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    Manager.add(mnbtn);

    cl.show(Bucket, "1");

    setTitle("NOVA PHARM");

    getContentPane().add(Bucket);
    setBounds(300, 300, 566, 482);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(5, 5));
    setResizable(true);


    }
    /**
    * Launch the application.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    try {
    NHome window = new NHome();
    window.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    });
    }
    }

    /* 
    *this is the second class where I want to use the variable
    */
```

Class 2

```
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import java.awt.Font;

    public class csView extends JPanel {

    /**
    * Create the panel.
    */
    public csView() {
    setLayout(null);
    /**
    * I want to display the String hhhhh in the JLabel Uniqlbl below
    *   
    */
    JLabel Uniqlbl = new JLabel("Cashier Name:");
    Uniqlbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    Uniqlbl.setBounds(227, 62, 253, 46);
    add(Uniqlbl);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). The idea is to create a model which maintains the formation which needs to be shared between the views

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: If this question is solved, please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify the csView

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;

public class csView extends JPanel {
    // Declare those variables here
    String hhhhh;
    JLabel Uniqlbl;

    public csView() {
        setLayout(null);

        Uniqlbl = new JLabel("Cashier Name:");
        Uniqlbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        Uniqlbl.setBounds(227, 62, 253, 46);
        add(Uniqlbl);

    }

    // Add a setter here
    public void setHhhhh(String hhhhh) {
        this.hhhhh = hhhhh;
        // Edit: Add this line to update the Uniqlbl text
        Uniqlbl.setText(hhhhh);
    }
}
```

And in the ActionListener call the setHhhhh() method

```
stbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        cl.show(Bucket, "2");

        String hhhhh=new String("Peter");

        // Call the setter here
        Cashier.setHhhhh(hhhhh);

        System.out.println(hhhhh);
    }
});
```

I suggest you not to use the "hhhhh" variable in the csView constructor or you could stumble in a NullPointerException. Or, if you want to do so, initialize the "hhhhh" variable first like this

```
String hhhhh = "";
```

Comment: Still doesn't show the value of 'hhhhh' in csView when I run it. @aleb2000

Comment: Try with the edited code. I forgot to call the `setText()` method for the `Uniqlbl` to update the text in the label, now it should work. @HarrietBani

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is a create a static variable in your NHome class that acts as a global variable. This would mean than csView would be able to read and write to the variable.

This is an example of how it could be implemented:

```
JPanel Bucket = new JPanel(), Start = new JPanel(), Cashier = new csView(), Manager = new JPanel();
JButton stbtn = new JButton("Start"), mnbtn = new JButton("Manager"), csbtn = new JButton("Cashier");
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
private JPasswordField passwordField;
static String hhhhh; //create the variable here


public NHome() {
        textField.setBounds(322, 141, 158, 31);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        Bucket.setLayout(cl);
        Bucket.add(Start, "1");
        Bucket.add(Cashier, "2");
        Bucket.add(Manager, "3");

        Start.setLayout(null);
        stbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cl.show(Bucket, "2");

                /*
                 * I want to use this value of this String in the another class (csView)
                 */
                hhhhh = new String("Peter"); //set the value here
                System.out.println(hhhhh);
            }
        });
```

So then you could implement it in your csView by saying:

```
JLabel Uniqlbl = new JLabel(NHome.hhhhh);
```

Comment: Can we please stop recommending `static` as a solution for cross class communication. A better solution might be to use a model between the two class and/or an observer pattern. `static` is a bad idea which encourages bad and lazy habits

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I see where you are coming from. I will take that into consideration before recommending it again. To be fair, it is up to the OP about whether or not she wants to develop those habits. She may want to solve the problem more than think about the long-term ramifications of the method.

Comment: Sorry the value is giving me null @Benjamin Lowry

Comment: If you don't initialize the static variable, and it hasn't passed through your actionPerformed method, then when you call it in another class it will be null. I recommend initializing it with something like "Default" or "No name"